# Slick2D - Same movement on every computer

Tags: time, slick2d

I am coding a game with friends and we have problems to get the same movement on our different PC. In Slick2D, we use the Delta to make the movement :

```
    if (input key up)
    {
        sprite = up; // changing the sprite
        if (no collision){
            sprite.update(delta*3); //animation
            y -= delta * 0.3f; // movement
        }
    }
```

The problem is that delta is the time between two frames. And this time in not the same on each computer because of performance. So the slower the computer is, the slower the movement will be.

How to solve this problem ?

Thank you for helping us, and I hope you understand my english !

Comment: You already figured it out: "The problem is that delta is the time between two frames. And this time in not the same on each computer because of performance. So the slower the computer is, the slower the movement will be" this will always result in the "same" pace of movement on different systems, because the delta might be higher but its not called as often as a lower delta obviously.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a target frame rate for your application?  It can normalize the speed of movement throughout all computers (given the computer can reach that rate).  So whenever you first instantiate your game class, do this:

```
private static final int TARGET_FRAME_RATE = 60;
private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 640;
private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 480;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        AppGameContainer appgc = new AppGameContainer(new MyGame());
        appgc.setDisplayMode(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, false);

        // Set the target framerate for the appgc
        appgc.setTargetFrameRate(TARGET_FRAME_RATE);

        appgc.start();
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        System.err.println("There was an error executing the game...");
        e.printStackTrace();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but if a computer can't play the game at the TARGET_FRAME_RATE, we have the same problem :/

Comment: How slow is the computer that it can't run a 2d game at 60 fps!? :P  But in reality, your usage of delta should keep that in track.  Maybe your computer is running the game below a playable rate.